# how to count the elements in a Pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe. It is a movie dataset. One column is the genres split by `|`. Each movie has multiple genres.

```
genres = spark.sql("SELECT DISTINCT genres FROM movies ORDER BY genres ASC")
genres.show(5)
```

[image]I would like to count each genre has how many movies. And I also want to show what are those movies. Just like the following:
[image][image]
How should I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to do:

```
# sample data
d = [('Action',), ('Action|Adventure',), ('Action|Adventure|Drama',)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(d, ['genres',])

# create count
agg_df = (df
          .rdd
          .map(lambda x: x.genres.split('|')) # gives nested list
          .flatMap(lambda x: x) # flatten the list
          .map(lambda x: (x,)) # convert to tuples
          .toDF(['genres'])
          .groupby('genres')
          .count())

agg_df.show()

+---------+-----+
|   genres|count|
+---------+-----+
|Adventure|    2|
|    Drama|    1|
|   Action|    3|
+---------+-----+
```

Comment: So is it possible not to convert to rdd and directly work on the dataframe?

Comment: yes, it is possible using udf functions but native spark functions have speed advantages.

Comment: Using DataFrame API does not imply using UDF, there are a lot of Spark built-in functions to do this. I added an answer to show one simple way.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way using only DataFrame API. First, use `split` function to split the `genres` strings then `explode` the result array and groupBy `genres` to count:

```
data = [["Action"], ["Action|Adventure|Thriller"], ["Action|Adventure|Drama"]]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["genres"])

df = df.withColumn("genres", explode(split(col("genres"), "[|]"))) \
    .groupBy("genres").count()

df.show()
```

Gives:

```
+---------+-----+
|   genres|count|
+---------+-----+
| Thriller|    1|
|Adventure|    2|
|    Drama|    1|
|   Action|    3|
+---------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df.groupby("generes").agg(f.collect_set("Category"),f.count("Category")).show()
```

this will get the desired output.